# dynamic link in jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, url-parameters

I want to add dynamic link to my jQueryMobile page.
This is my code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="categoriesList">
            <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c"><h4>Categories</h4></li>
            <li><a href="#dinamic?x=7&y=8" data-ajax="false">dinamic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#banner" data-rel="dialog">to banner</a></li>
        </ul>
```

How can I can get the value of x and y variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getParams(url){
    var results = {};
    var ps = url.split('?');

    // get string after '?' sign. if no '?' sign, then return empty object
    if(ps.length > 1)
       ps = ps[1];
    else
       return results;

    // get parameters split with '&' and split each one by '=' to get
    // name-value pairs
    var parts = ps.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
        var parts2 = parts[i].split('=');
        results[parts2[0]] = parts2[1];
    }
    return results;
}
```

EXAMPLE:

```
<li><a id="example" href="#dinamic?x=7&y=8" data-ajax="false">dinamic</a></li>
```

JS:

```
var url = document.getElementById('example').getAttribute('href');
var params = getParams(url);
console.log(params.x);
console.log(params.y);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xCrt3/)

Comment: a little bit more explanation abt what the code is doing might be helpful for novice ppl :-)

Comment: Hi. thank you! this is very simple and it work! so thank you!
But, it work only if i refresh. if i click on JQM button, this is not work, because it in ajax.